# Item task relation in list view

Tags: list, workflow, list-view, task-list

I have a worklfow that creates task in a custom task list. However, I also want to display the item that applies to the workflow task in the task list itself. How can I add this control to to the task list view?

I am working with SP 2010.

Comment: Not sure if you are looking to add a link to a document or just to the list item? Instead of using a task, I like creating an Approval instead. As far as I can tell, you cannot change anything within a task (very basic), while an Approval will allow you add/delete stuff as needed. You can go into the approval and change many different behaviors and definitely what is included.

Comment: I just need to add the item the task is associated with to the view, that's all there's to it.

Answer (score 0):

You can do this manually by doing the following (taken from this [stackfly blog entry](http://geekswithblogs.net/bjackett/archive/2011/02/18/sharepoint-designer-2010-email-link-to-item.aspx)):

- First add a “Send an Email” action to your workflow.  Edit the action to pull up the email configuration dialog.  Click the “Add hyperlink” button seen below.

[image]

- When prompted for the address of the link click the fx button to perform a lookup.  Choose Workflow Context from the “data source” dropdown.  Choose Current Item URL from the “field from source” dropdown.  Click OK.

[image]

- Your Edit Hyperlink dialog should now look something like this.

[image]

- The end result will be a hyperlink added to your email pointing to
  the current workflow item.  Note: this link points to the non-modal
  dialog display form (display form similar to what you had in 2007).

[image]

Hope this helps.

Comment: Hi Paulster2, thanks for your comment, but unfortunately this is not what I'm looking for. I'm trying to add the item ID to the task list view from within the workflow itself. My challenge is the WHERE statement. I can lookup a value from a list yes, but how can I update that field only in the tasks WHERE the workflow is x OR the current item = "y" ? Hope it is clear.

Comment: I was way off base, eh? I'm not really understanding then. Not sure if you are trying to add the ID to the Task List View for the overall site, or doing something with the notice within workflow which is sent out to your assignee. I take it you want to filter the output? Like I was saying above, I have had very little luck with modifying tasks. Because of this I use approvals instead, which are way more flexible. Maybe someone else can help you better than I.

Comment: Hi Paulster2, no issue :-) I am trying to achive the first "add the ID to the Task List View for the overall site". I also noticed approvals are more flexible, but even then I don't know if it can be achieved what I'm trying.